# Get id of $(".selected") when delete key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the id of a object that has the class "selected" when the delete key is pressed in the document.

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 46) {
        alert($('.selected').attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Don't know why this doesn't work...

http://jsfiddle.net/aWVFw/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aWVFw/1/   Open your console next time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$(doccument).keyup(function (e) {
```

with this:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
```

It should be `document` not `doccument`.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aWVFw/3/) (*Include the jQuery file also from left side* `Frameworks & Extensions` *section*)

Comment: woops typo, but that doesn't fix it

Comment: @Koiski See the demo and also include the jQuery file :)

Comment: i forgot to add jquery -.- haha well thanks stupid me..

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$(doccument).keyup(function (e) {
```

with

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
```

and see this working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aWVFw/6/)

You didnt load any jquery library that's why its not getting as per your expectation...See my fiddle left Frameworks and extensions.I have added Jquery 1.8.3

Comment: was a typo, fixed the typo but not the problem..

Answer (score 2):

As well as fixing the `doccument` typo, you have to actually load the jQuery library. On JS Fiddle, that is done by picking it from the menu on the left.

Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/aWVFw/5/

Other possible contributors to the problem:

- You might be pressing Backspace instead of Delete. They have different keycodes so make sure you press the right key.
- You might not have focused the document containing the JS (by clicking in it) so the key event is being received by the wrong `document`.

Answer (score 2):

From your JSFiddle, there is no jQuery declared.
[image: Without jQuery]
Please include the jQuery framework.